# bash script to bulk decode files

Tags: bash, linux

I have written script that does the following. It uses `cbl-log` program to decode several log files in binary format. `cbl-log` only decodes 1 file at a time, so the script decodes files in bulk. If no arguments are given, it assumes log files (with extension .cbllog) are in the current directory, and it'll output files to `decoded` directory. Otherwise you need to give 2 arguments. The first is the directory with all cbllog files, and the second is the output directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# == 1 || $# > 2 )); then
    echo "Usage:    cbldecode"  
    echo "          cbldecode <source directory> <target directory>"
    exit 1
fi

cmd="$(command -v {./,}cbl-log | head -n1)"
if [[ -z "$cmd" ]] ; then
   echo "cbl-log should be in PATH or current directory"
   exit 1
fi   

log_dir=${1:-$PWD}
out_dir=${2:-"decoded"}
count=$(find "$log_dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cbllog" | wc -l) 

if (( "$count" == 0 )); then
    echo "no cbllog files in source directory"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ -d "$out_dir" ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$out_dir"
elif ! [[ -w "$out_dir" ]]; then
    echo "no write permission to $out_dir"
    exit 1
fi

for path in "$log_dir"/*.cbllog; do
    file=${path//$log_dir/}
    out_file="${file%.cbllog}"
    "$cmd" logcat "$path" "$out_dir"/"$out_file"
done
```

While this works, I'm looking for ways to make the code more compact and optimize for speed.

Comment: Can you add the specific things you want to be reviewed for this question, such as if you followed general practices and/or if you want to know how to optimize it?

Comment: @K00lman looking for ways to make code more compact, and any time optimizations.

Comment: Could you add that to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-u` and `-e` switches to bash, when possible, because they help to find bugs.  Your log decoder may return errors that you want to ignore (making `-e` unhelpful) but `-u` is safe here.

Move the `echo … exit` pattern into a function:

```
die() { printf "%s\n" "$@" >&2; exit 1; }
```

Quotes aren't needed on the left-hand side of `[[` tests.  For "die unless foo" assertions, consider writing them in the form `foo || die "test failed"`:

```
[[ -z $cmd ]] && die "…"
```

`(( $# == 1 || $# > 2 ))` is more clearly written in the affirmative, as `(( $# == 0 || $# == 2 ))`

Collect the file list once instead of twice.  Use globbing instead of `find` to get proper handling of filenames with spaces in them.  Include contributing variables in error messages.  Do a `cd` first so that you don't need to decompose filenames later.  `((` expressions return false when zero so there's usually no need to explicitly write `x == 0`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
pushd "$log_dir" || die "can't chdir to $log_dir"
declare -a in=( *.cbllog )
popd || die "can't return to original working directory"
(( ${#in} )) || die "no cbllog files in $log_dir"
…
for path in "${in[@]}"; do
```

Your command detector has a bug if `cbl-log` is an alias or function.  Use `type -P` instead.  If you truncate using `read` instead of `head`, the assignment doubles as an emptyness test:

```
read cmd < <( type -P {./,}cbl-log ) || die "cbl-log should be in PATH or current directory"
```

Your basename implementation has a bug if `log_dir` contains globbing characters.  This is obsoleted by the `pushd` above but something like `file=${path##*/}` or `file=$( basename "$path" )` would work.

`mkdir -p` is a no-op when the directory exists; no need to test for that yourself.

You'll need execute permission on `$out_dir` along with write.

Putting it all together:

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash -u 
    die() { printf "%s\n" "$@" >&2; exit 1; }

    (( ${#} == 0 || ${#} == 2 )) || die "Usage:    cbldecode"  "          cbldecode <source directory> <target directory>"
    log_dir=${1:-$PWD}
    out_dir=${2:-"decoded"}
    read cmd < <( type -P {./,}cbl-log ) || die "cbl-log should be in PATH or current directory"

    pushd "$log_dir" || die "can't chdir to $log_dir"
    shopt -s nullglob
    declare -a in=( *.cbllog )
    popd || die "can't return to original working directory"
    (( ${#in} )) || die "no cbllog files in $log_dir"

    mkdir -p "$out_dir"
    [[ -w $out_dir && -x $out_dir ]] || die "insufficient permissions on $out_dir"

    for basename in "${in[@]}"; do 
        "$cmd" logcat "$log_dir/$basename" "$out_dir/${basename%.cbllog}"
    done
```

For faster conversion, add `&` to the `cbl-log` invocation, or adapt the script to send basenames to `xargs -P`.

Comment: Fantastic feedback.  I noticed `pushd` displays stack in stdout so added `1>/dev/null` to it.  I think we can use `-e` if we add `|| true` to the line that does log decoding, right?  Finally I'm using macos so 'type -P` is invalid, unfortunately.  Any alternatives?

Comment: Yes `|| true` will satisfy `-e`.  Prepend `.` to `$PATH` and invoke the command with a do-nothing switch like `-v` or `-help`.  If that fails, throw error.  Adding cwd to PATH is not a safe practice in general.  It's fine here since the whole script is shell builtins.  To make it safer declare a function like `cmd(){ local PATH=.:$PATH; cbl-log "$@"; }` so only that one command is affected by the unsafe PATH.

Comment: That worked for me.  Thanks.